# Double Integral form of the nth Harmonic Number

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Consider the double integral
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 n(1-xy)^{n-1}dx dy.$$
Entering this double integral into Wolfram Alpha gives that it is equal to the $n^{th}$ harmonic number, where the $n^{th}$ harmonic number denotes $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$. 
Now when I first saw this result, I didn't initially believe it and I tested it out by trying discrete, integer values of n until I was finally convinced. I wanted to ask and see if anyone could help me understand the intuition behind why this integral results in the Harmonic series, perhaps similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540699/nth-harmonic-number-proof). Essentially, it's just hard for me to see the connection between this integral and the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double integral can be evaluated by repeated integration.
\begin{gather*}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}n(1-xy)^{n-1}\,dxdy = \int_{0}^{1}\left[\dfrac{(1-xy)^{n}}{-x}\right]_{0}^{1}\, dx = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-(1-x)^{n}}{x}\,dx =[x=1-z] = \\[2ex] \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-z^{n}}{1-z}\, dz = H_{n}
\end{gather*}
where I have used your suggested link.